# JSON representation of the current Terraform configuration

Tags: terraform, cloud, infrastructure-as-code

I want to have a clear, machine-readable (e.g. JSON) representation of all the resources that are currently defined in my Terraform project, along with all of the resource configs/options. Is there a way to do that?

The `tfstate` file is not what I need, because that is a representation of the state, not the current configuration.

The `tfplan` file kind of contains the information I want, but upon closer inspection, it seems much more complex and difficult to work with. So it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of a Terraform configuration and your desired JSON from that

Answer (score 1):

This may help you: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/show

```
terraform show -json
```

*The terraform show command is used to provide human-readable output from a state or plan file. This can be used to inspect a plan to ensure that the planned operations are expected, or to inspect the current state as Terraform sees it.
Machine-readable output is generated by adding the -json command-line flag.*

Alternatively: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan

```
terraform plan - json
```

*-json - Enables the machine readable JSON UI output. This implies -input=false, so the configuration must have no unassigned variable values to continue.*

Answer (score 0):

I would add something more to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242266/13347227). To get all options for the resources that are in defined providers you can use command:

```
terraform providers schema -json
```

Part of the output from this command:

```
"google_storage_bucket_iam_member": {
  "version": 0,
  "block": {
    "attributes": {
      "bucket": {
        "type": "string",
        "description_kind": "plain",
        "required": true
      },
      "etag": {
        "type": "string",
        "description_kind": "plain",
        "computed": true
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "description_kind": "plain",
        "optional": true,
        "computed": true
      },
      "member": {
        "type": "string",
        "description_kind": "plain",
        "required": true
      },
      "role": {
        "type": "string",
        "description_kind": "plain",
        "required": true
      }
    },
    "block_types": {
      "condition": {
        "nesting_mode": "list",
        "block": {
          "attributes": {
            "description": {
              "type": "string",
              "description_kind": "plain",
              "optional": true
            },
            "expression": {
              "type": "string",
              "description_kind": "plain",
              "required": true
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "description_kind": "plain",
              "required": true
            }
          },
          "description_kind": "plain"
        },
        "max_items": 1
      }
    },
    "description_kind": "plain"
  }
}
```

You can combine `terraform show -json` with `terraform providers schema -json` to achieve your goals.